# Get back values from column if two other columns dont meet filter criteria

Tags: dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 Name     Value   Value1  C1   C2    C3
  A        1       2      NA   NA    NA
  A        NA      2      NA   2     NA
  A        1       2      NA   2     NA
  A        1       2      NA   2     NA
  A        1       2      NA   2     NA
  B        NA      1      NA   2     NA
  B        NA      2      NA   2     NA
  B        1       NA     NA   2     NA
  B        1       NA     NA   2     NA
  C        1       5      NA   2     NA
  C        1       5      NA   2     NA

  dt <- as.data.table(df)
  new <- dt[is.na(`Value`) == FALSE & is.na(`Value1`) == FALSE,]
```

would give me the following output:

```
 Name     Value   Value1  C1   C2    C3
  A        1       2      NA   NA    NA
  A        1       2      NA   2     NA
  A        1       2      NA   2     NA
  A        1       2      NA   2     NA
  C        1       5      NA   2     NA
  C        1       5      NA   2     NA
```

Is there a way of doing this, but instead of filtering the rows, I want to have all letters in my column Name which dont meet my filter criteria.
So in this example, I would like to get back A and B because A has one row that does not have for both columns Value and Value1 non-na-values and B does not meet the criteria at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RonakShah has already pointed out (using `base-R`) how to `filter` out rows for `Name` which got at least 1 `NA` in `Value` or `Value1` columns.

But, perhaps, OP is looking for just `unique` names instead of full subset of rows. In `dplyr` this can be done as:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), any_vars(is.na(.))) %>%  #Either Value or Value1 
  select(Name) %>% distinct()

# Name 
# <chr>
# 1 A    
# 2 B
```

To get the full rows for `Name` having any `NA` in `Value` or `Value1`

```
df %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(any(is.na(Value) | any(is.na(Value1))))

  #   Name  Value Value1 C1       C2 C3   
  #  <chr> <int>  <int> <lgl> <int> <lgl>
  # 1 A         1      2 NA       NA NA   
  # 2 A        NA      2 NA        2 NA   
  # 3 A         1      2 NA        2 NA   
  # 4 A         1      2 NA        2 NA   
  # 5 A         1      2 NA        2 NA   
  # 6 B        NA      1 NA        2 NA   
  # 7 B        NA      2 NA        2 NA   
  # 8 B         1     NA NA        2 NA   
  # 9 B         1     NA NA        2 NA
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Name     Value   Value1  C1   C2    C3
A        1       2      NA   NA    NA
A        NA      2      NA   2     NA
A        1       2      NA   2     NA
A        1       2      NA   2     NA
A        1       2      NA   2     NA
B        NA      1      NA   2     NA
B        NA      2      NA   2     NA
B        1       NA     NA   2     NA
B        1       NA     NA   2     NA
C        1       5      NA   2     NA
C        1       5      NA   2     NA",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!` as the negation operator. (In fact, you should already be using it instead of `== FALSE`. Also, you don't need backticks unless your column names are strange (they have spaces or something).

```
# your code, rewritten with ! instead of == FALSE
df[!is.na(Value) & !is.na(Value1), ]

# negate it to get the opposite
# same as above, but with !( your logic )
df[!(!is.na(Value) & !is.na(Value1)), ]
   Name Value Value1 C1 C2 C3
1:    A    NA      2 NA  2 NA
2:    B    NA      1 NA  2 NA
3:    B    NA      2 NA  2 NA
4:    B     1     NA NA  2 NA
5:    B     1     NA NA  2 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I might have misunderstood you but as far as I could read the description, I think you meant get all the rows of particular `Name` that has atleast one `NA` in them.

This can be done using `ave` where we check if there is atleast one `NA` in `Value` or `Value1` column and then select that entire group (`Name`).

```
df[with(df, ave(is.na(Value) | is.na(Value1), Name, FUN = any)), ]


 #  Name Value Value1 C1 C2 C3
 #1    A     1      2 NA NA NA
 #2    A    NA      2 NA  2 NA
 #3    A     1      2 NA  2 NA
 #4    A     1      2 NA  2 NA
 #5    A     1      2 NA  2 NA
 #6    B    NA      1 NA  2 NA
 #7    B    NA      2 NA  2 NA
 #8    B     1     NA NA  2 NA
 #9    B     1     NA NA  2 NA
```